# Black Hole Information Paradox: Why Isn't the Position of A Black Hole Count as Part of Its "Information"?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes

It's often said that a black hole only has three properties:

1. its mass
2. its electric charge, and
3. its angular momentum

Why isn't it's position and velocity relative to other objects part of this "information"?

Comment: Mass, charge and angular momentum can be observed, and they aren't "information", as the term is used in "information paradox".

Comment: Isn't it as simple as this:  position and velocity, *relative* to other objects, are not *properties* (properly understood) of an entity?

Comment: If you replace the words "black hole" with "milk coffee", then you end up with the exact same physical question as Hawking formulated about black holes. How does quantum mechanics untangle milk and coffee? The answer is the same as for black holes: it doesn't. Just my two cents...

Comment: Why isn't relative position and velocity information that defines a black hole? Assuming that mass going into a black hole moves the black hole or other stars slightly relative to another point, wouldn't this movement count as information?

Answer (score 1):

The position of an object is not an absolute quantity. There is no absolute meaning to position, because all you can do is define an object's position relative to some other object. For example you might say Cygnus X-1 (an archetypal black hole) is 6070 light years from the Sun in a specific direction, and define its position that way. The trouble is that an alien on the planet Zob would define the position of Cygnus X-1 in a completely different way. Neither of you is wrong, and neither is right, because position isn't absolute.

The same applies to velocity. You can only define velocity relative to some other object.

But mass, charge and angular momentum are absolute quantities because they have an unambiguous meaning for zero. Zero mass means, well, no mass is present and likewise zero charge means no charge is present. All observers will agree on the meaning of zero mass and charge, so absolute vaues of mass and charge can be measured relative to these zero points.

It's a little harder to understand why angular momentum is an absolute quantity, but it's because a spinning system always has forces related to the rotation i.e. the centrifugal and centripetal forces. We can define zero angular momentum by requiring that these forces be zero, and again all observers will agree what constitutes zero angular momentum.

And that's why (rest) mass, charge and angular momentum are special. It's because all observers will agree on their values (up to a choice of units).

Comment: Can we add zero temperature and zero entropy if Hawking radiation is observed one day?

Comment: @Jitter: that's a bit tricky. I'm not sure that the zero of temperature is an absolute. For example someone falling freely into the black hole would not observe any Hawking radiation i.e. they would measure the black hole temperature to be zero while a shell observer would measure the temperature to be non-zero. In any case the temperature is just a function of the mass, charge and spin, so it isn't a fourth independant quantity. I think the same applies to entropy.

Comment: Does charge include colour/color charge?

Comment: Hi John, I understand your points re "absolute" position/velocity, that's why my question explicitly stated relative position/velocity. Why isn't relative position and velocity information that defines a black hole? Assuming that mass going into a black hole moves the black hole or other stars slightly relative to another point, wouldn't this movement count as information?

Comment: @speedplane: A black hole can be identified only by its detectable effect on surrounding objects and matter, as well as by the emission of x-rays and radio wavelengths from matter being pulled into a black hole.  See this link for black hole detection: http://minerva.union.edu/vianil/web_stuff2/detection_of_Black_Holes.htm.  So implicitly the position of a black hole becomes part of its description and identifying information, though it certainly is not a property.

Comment: @Jitter: in principle yes, though nothing bigger than a quark will have a net colour charge so in practice no.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the properties of a static or stationary black hole. Other objects can, ... over time start to have outsides that look closer and closer yo one of those.

The position and velocity aren't even physical properties. Only relative position and relative velocity are physical. Just adjust your origin to move a black hole and just boost your frame to have it look like it is moving compared to that frame.

Answer (score 0):

The three you listed are *internal* physical properties, whereas position is external

Perhaps position as a function of time would also work. Mass *does* change with speed, which can be determined via x(t)...
But it's not considered among the three ***because they don't uniquely define a black holes properties and they are not physical properties themselves***.